# Ругается при выводе данных с БД

Tags: php, mysql

Пересмотрел код ,скорее всего здесь не хватает знака ,возможно где-то не закрыл тег ,хоть пересмотрел уже весь код несколько раз.

```
<body>
<?php
    $host="localhost";    
    $user="root";        
    $pass="a-1800";             
    $db_name="test_base";   
    $link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db_name); 
    $cod=mysqli_set_charset( $link,'utf8' );

?>
<div id=TAB_1 style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:600px">
<table border='2'  class="all" style="width:800px;height:300px">
<tr>
    <td>№ </td>
    <td>ФРАКЦИИ</td>
    <td>ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ</td>
</tr>
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($link ,"SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Price` FROM `products`");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $str=mb_convert_encoding('products', "UTF-8", "cp-1251");
    echo     '<tr><td>'.$result['ID'].'</td>'.
             '<td>'.$result['Name'].'</td>'.
             '<td>'.$result['Price'].'%</td>'.
} -ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА
?>
</table>
<table id="tab">
<form action=""class="tab_all" method="POST">
    <tr>
        <td class="fraktion">ФРАКЦИИ:</td>
        <td><input type="text"class="name" name="Name"size="8" value="<?php echo ($result['Name']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="input_db">ВЫВОД :</td>
        <td class="time"><input  type="number" class="info" name="Price"  value="<?php echo ($result['Price']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>

</form>
</table>
    </div> 

</body>
```

Comment: Потому что скобка расположена в недопустимом по синтаксису месте. Хинт: см. предыдущую строку.

Comment: Что значит в недопустимом по синтаксису месте? Фигурная скобка может быть расположена где угодно.

Comment: Хинт(не по теме): изменение кодировки слова `products` выглядит бесполезным...

Comment: @robertobadjo не в любом. В частности, после оператора конкатенации - не может.

Comment: @Мелкий Да. Здесь у него не закончена инструкция, не хватает точки с запятой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точка с запятой в конце

```
'<td>'.$result['Price'].'%</td>';
}
```